# why plotting a normalized autocorrelation gives positives and negatives values?

Tags: python, autocorrelation

I used the following code to compute and plot autocorrelation function ACF for an array as follows:

```
an_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
autocorrelation = np.correlate(an_array, an_array, mode="full")
ACF= autocorrelation[autocorrelation.size//2:]
print(ACF)
```

**Output**

[55 40 26 14  5]

Then, I calculated the normalized ACF as follows:

```
Normalized_ACF = (ACF- ACF.min(axis=0)) / (ACF.max(axis=0) - ACF.min(axis=0)) 
print(Normalized_ACF)
```

**Output**

[1.   0.7  0.42 0.18 0.]

This output is correct.

However, when I used another method using "plot.acf" built-in function in python to compute and plot the normalized ACF of the array, it gives me other values (positive and negatives) as follows.

```
from statsmodels.graphics import tsaplots
# Display the autocorrelation plot of your time series
fig = tsaplots.plot_acf(an_array, lags=3)
plt.show()
```

**Output of the 2nd method:**

[image]

Can anyone interprets why the two methods give different outputs?